# how can I rotate obj mtl object in animation

Tags: javascript, rotation, three.js

I've exhausted all the postings related to this problem and have spent the entire weekend changing everything I can think of trying to rotate an obj mtl in the animation function. Nothing works.

The code is in threejs and I have added all the libraries etc and declared the objmtl object globally. I CAN rotate the object in this code:

```
loader1 = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
                loader1.load( 'head_no_eyes.obj', 'head_no_eyes.mtl',
                function ( object1 ) {
                object1.position.y = - 10;
                object1.rotation.x =  Math.PI/15.;
                scene.add( object1 );
                animate();
                } );
```

but NOT in the animation routine:

```
function animate() { 
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * 0.5;
            camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * .05;
        //  object1.rotation.y += 0.07;  // this line makes it fail
            camera.lookAt(scene.position);
            renderer.render(scene, camera); }
```

I can't imagine why not. Has anybody got a clue about why this doesn't work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're having a simple problem about JavaScript scopes.

```
function ( object1 ) {
    object1.position.y = - 10;
    object1.rotation.x =  Math.PI/15.;
    scene.add( object1 );
    animate();
} );
```

With that code `object1` is only accessible inside that specific callback. `animate()` can't access it. Meaning that you're trying to modify a `rotation` property of an undefined object.

Try with this code instead:

```
function ( object ) {
    object1 = object;
    object1.position.y = - 10;
    object1.rotation.x =  Math.PI/15.;
    scene.add( object1 );
    animate();
} );
```

Comment: Dank Doob. Sie sind ein guter Mensch.